# Como ejecutar una Shiny app con un boton en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, flexdasboard

Estoy armando en R un FlexDasboard con Shiny, uso Flex porque me parce mas sencillo de armar visualmente (Opinión personal).
Tengo un script que toma 2 variables y hace unos cálculos para dar un `Dataframe`como resultado. Eso funciona perfecto.
Ahora lo que quiero hacer, es convertir todo esto en una app Shiny, en donde coloque por medio de ````fileinput``` mis variables y haga los cálculos correspondientes.

```
#Cargo mis librerias y con source llamo al script que me hace todos los calculos
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
source("test.R")
```

```
#Subo mis 2 archivos 
fileInput("file1", "Archivo1", accept = ".xlsx")

fileInput("file2", "Archivo2", accept = ".xlsx")

actionButton("ejecutar", "Ejecutar")
```

```
#Muestro con Render, mis 2 archivos en la interfaz y funciona perfecto
renderDT({
  file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)

    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a Excel file"))

    Archivo1 = read_excel(file$datapath, 1)
  })
```

Les dejo una imagen de como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que no se como poner el botón de Ejecutar para que una vez suba mis archivos, corra todo el script que tengo armado.
He probado con `eventReactive()` y con `Observe()` pero no hace ninguna acción, creo que el problema es que no lo estoy linkeando con los input.

Alguna ayuda o idea?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Rodrigo que esperas en la salida de tu shiny app una tabla con el df que resulta? Una grafica?  ambos?  Por ahora te recomiendo cheques la función  `observeEvent`. Se me ocurre algo como `observeEvent(input$ejecutar,{codigo que genera el df y la salida})`, lo anterior en el server y naturalmente definir la salida también en el ui.

Comment: Rolando, mi salida es una tabla como df tal como lo has dicho, he probado tu opción pro el botón de ejecutar no hace nada, no se si con este código que puse esta guardando mi variable en memoria o no. Todavía no doy con la solucion

Comment: Con el código que compartiste en la pregunta no estas generando ninguna salida. Y al parecer tampoco guardas la variable en un df. Solo cargas el archivo, lees los datos pero no los guardas. Una un valor reactivo para guardarlos p.e. `rv$df<-renderDT({..` luego con `rv$df` puedes hacer los cálculos como los haces en r normal y generar la salida. Te sugiero de nuevo compartas el todo el código como lo estas usando para hacer la app y una pequeña muestra de tus datos

Comment: El codigo funciona bien, pero no me esta asignando al input la variable ( el archivo que subo) Si cargo el archivo normal, la app funciona. Como podria asignar un nombre al archivo que subo ?

Comment: Por ejemplo, puedes guardarlo en un valor reactivo como te menciono en el comentario anterior. Hay otras opciones pero sin el código  del ui y el server no se como más apoyarte, pues no queda claro lo que estas haciendo.

Comment: Rolando, gracias por tu comentario, pero es que no es la clásica ui con server, es con FlexDashboard como dice el cuerpo del mensaje, no funciona como Shiny solo. Sino que flex canaliza el ui y server con Rmarkdown. El código que compartí, es el que tengo en toda la app.

Comment: A ok. Entonces el código que compartes arriba es todo el código que tienes?

Comment: Exacto, solo que no he logrado guardar el Excel que subo como un df o tabla para seguir trabajando con él. Solo lo veo, pero no lo puedo guardar como te comento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En seguida adjunto el código de una app en flexdashboard que podría ayudarte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cree dos archivos excel con una columna de datos solamente cada 1. La aplicación lee cada archivo y los muestra. Luego al dar clic en ejecutar multiplica las columnas de los dos archivos y muestra el resultado.

El paquete `flexdashboard` funciona de manera similar a `shiny` cuando hacer una aplicación. Hemos usado dos `eventReactive` para guardar los data frames generados al leer los `archivos`. En `shiny` el control de objetos es un poco distinto a R normal debido a la reactividad de la aplicación, de echo el concepto de reactividad y su control es toda la base para dominar `shiny`.

Como sugerencia trata de investigar mas sobre este concepto, puedes empezar leyendo la documentación de [eventReactive](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html).

Después usamos `observeEvent` para indicar a `shiny` que ejecute un calculo con los datos leídos al dar clic al `actioButton` ejecutar.

Nota que usamos **df1()** y **df2()** para hacer el calculo, en lugar de `df1` y `df2` como seria en R normal. Esto también tiene que ver con el comportamiento reactivo de `shiny`.

````
---
title: "Como ejecutar una Shiny app con un boton"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    social: menu
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
#Cargo mis librerias y con source llamo al script que me hace todos los calculos
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
#Subo mis 2 archivos 
fileInput("file1", "Archivo1", accept = ".xlsx")

fileInput("file2", "Archivo2", accept = ".xlsx")

actionButton("ejecutar", "Ejecutar")
```

Outputs
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
#Muestro con Render, mis 2 archivos en la interfaz y funciona perfecto
df1<-eventReactive(input$file1,{
  file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)

    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a Excel file"))

    read_excel(file$datapath, 1)
  })

renderDT(df1())
```

### Chart C

```{r}
#Muestro con Render, mis 2 archivos en la interfaz y funciona perfecto
df2<-eventReactive(input$file2,{
  file <- input$file2
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)

    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a Excel file"))

    read_excel(file$datapath, 1)
  })

renderDT(df2())
```

### Chart D

```{r}
#Controlamos cuando ejecutar el calculo con el actionButton
observeEvent(input$ejecutar,{

  #Hacemos un calculo con las variables
  aux<-data.frame(z=df1()[,1]*df2()[,1])
  output$resultado<-renderDT(aux)
})

DTOutput("resultado")
```
````

**Los cambios que tienes que hacer**

En tu script seguramente ya tienes un nombre para las variables que guardan los archivos, como ejemplo digamos que ese nombre es `df`. Para empezar lo que tienes que cambiar es la forma en la que creas esas variables, ya no es simplemente con read.xlsx si no que tienes que leerlo con el `eventReactive` como lo muestro en la respuesta. Enseguida toda la parte del calculo que tengas en tu script debe estar dentro del `observeEvent` para que se ejecute solo cuando cambie el `input$ejecutar`. y último después de que creas `df`, cuando lo uses tienes que cambiarlo por `df()` y va a funcionar todo igual. Lo que puedes hacer es un buscar y remplazar con algún editor de texto para que lo cambie todo de una vez. Guarda tu script original antes.

Comment: Gracias Rolando, entendí el concepto, ahora lo difícil es aplicar esto a un script que ya tienes armado, ya que la variable o tabla para trabajar (siguiendo tu ejemplo) deja de ser df y pasa a ser df(). Habria que modificar varias cosas no? Un saludo

Comment: Rodrigo he editad la respuesta agregando un apartado con los cambios que tienes que hacer. En síntesis  cuando lo uses `df` tienes que cambiarlo por `df()`.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo Puedes ayudarme? Acabo de publicar una pregunta sobre Shiny. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/580348/c%c3%b3mo-usar-un-archivo-y-el-comando-fileinput-para-modificar-una-shiny-app-en-r