# Cómo usar un archivo y el comando fileInput para modificar una Shiny App en R?

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy tratando de aprender Shiny con R.

El desafío es:

1. Bajar un archivo con las columnas seleccionadas.
2. Subir ese archivo y usarlo para construir un subset de un dataframe con esas columnas.

En mi ejemplo, he logrado construir la opción de upload y de download.

El archivo de download está trabajando muy bien.

El botón de upload también.

Sin embargo, estoy haciendo trampa y construyendo el subset en forma manual con un vector que he creado (***my_selection***).

En definitiva, no sé cómo usar el archivo de subida, para asignarlo al vector my_selection.

Pueden por favor ayudarme?

Aquí está mi código.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "diamonds_subset"'

      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"),
                 p("Filtered Variables"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("filtered_variables"),
                 downloadButton(outputId = "download_my_variables", label = "Download My Variables")),
        tabPanel("diamonds_subset", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable_subset"),
                 helpText("Please Upload a File to Create a Subset."),
                 fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload...", multiple = FALSE),
                 tableOutput("files"))
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  # choose columns to display
  my_selection = c("carat", "cut", "color")
  diamonds_subset = diamonds[, my_selection ]
  output$mytable_subset <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds_subset[, , drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  
  output$files <- renderTable(input$upload)
  
  
  output$filtered_variables <- 
    renderPrint({
      input$show_vars
    })
  
  output$download_my_variables <- 
    downloadHandler(
      filename = "my_variables.csv",
      content = function(file){
        write. Table(input$show_vars, file, row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=",")
      }
    )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: que esperas obtener en el output 'files', no seria lo mismo que 'mytable_subset'. O quieres que muestre un texto con las variables que subes como se muestran las que seleccionas en el primer panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He modificado el código para que tratar de lograr lo que pides, en comentarios he explicado un poco mejor los cambios.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        'input.dataset === "diamonds_subset"'

      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds",
                 DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"),
                 p("Filtered Variables"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("filtered_variables"),
                 downloadButton(outputId = "download_my_variables", label = "Download My Variables")),
        tabPanel("diamonds_subset", 
                 DT::dataTableOutput("mytable_subset"),
                 helpText("Please Upload a File to Create a Subset."),
                 fileInput("upload", NULL, buttonLabel = "Upload...", multiple = FALSE),
                 tableOutput("files"),
               DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table"))
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE])
  })
  

  #Leemos el contenido del archivo cargado
  vars_upload <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$upload
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = F,sep = input$separator)
    return(df)
    #Nota: read.table regresa un df, si quieres
    #las variables como vector seria con df$V1
  })
  

  #Creamos una salida para mostrar el contenido del archivo cargado
  output$sample_table<- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- vars_upload()
    DT::datatable(df)
  })

  # choose columns to display
  #my_selection = c("carat", "cut", "color")
  #diamonds_subset = diamonds[, my_selection ]
  output$mytable_subset <- DT::renderDataTable({
    my_selection = vars_upload()$V1
    diamonds_subset = diamonds[, my_selection ]
    DT::datatable(diamonds_subset[, , drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  
  output$files <- renderTable(input$upload)
  
  
  output$filtered_variables <- 
    renderPrint({
      input$show_vars
    })
  
  output$download_my_variables <- 
    downloadHandler(
      filename = "my_variables.csv",
      content = function(file){
        write.table(input$show_vars, file, row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=",")
      }
    )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta: Cuando usas df <- read.table(inFile$datapath, header = F, sep = input$separator) De dónde sale input$separator?

Comment: Una disculpa lo he dejado de un código que tenia, puedes omitirlo. O si deseas leer distintos tipos de archivos (separados por comas, espacios, tabulación, etc) puedes crear un input separador en el ui.

Comment: Si es factible, por favor ayúdame con esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/581228/r-c%c3%b3mo-grabar-la-shiny-session