# R: Cómo grabar la Shiny Session?

Tags: r

Quiero grabar la Shiny session en R. Lo he logrado usando la opción ***bookmarkButton()*** Genera un link que se puede usar luego y la app se abre en el lugar que se generó el link. ***Sin embargo, cuando grabo, no quedan grabados los filtros de la table que usa el DT package***. Alguien puede ayudarme con esto? Lo demás está funcionando muy bien. De antemano, muchísimas gracias!

Este es el link del Código. Por si acaso, lo quieren descargar desde GitHub: https://github.com/BeginnerStackOverflow/StackOverflowDrafts/blob/3e1e90aabe4b9ca008cd055d6c7443e8e260e1a5/STACKOVERFLOW_DRAFT_FEB_1_2023.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset

ui <- function(request) {fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "mtcars"',
        helpText("Click the column header to sort a column.")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "iris"',
        helpText("Display 5 records by default.")
      ),
      bookmarkButton()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        tabPanel("mtcars", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
        tabPanel("iris", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable3"))
      )
    )
  )
)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE], filter = "top")
  )
  
  
  # sorted columns are colored now because CSS are attached to them
  output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
  })
  
  # customize the length drop-down menu; display 5 rows per page by default
  output$mytable3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente código logra una buena aproximación de lo que necesitas, dejos comentarios en el código explicandolo.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset
    library(DT)
    library(jsonlite)
    
    
    # Valor por default del ilatro general
    if (!exists("default_search")) default_search <- ""
    
    # Valores por default de los filtors por columna
    if (!exists("default_search_columns")) default_search_columns <- NULL
    
    set.seet(1234)
    diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
    
    
   library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)  # for the diamonds dataset
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)


# Valor por default del ilatro general
if (!exists("default_search")) default_search <- ""

# Valores por default de los filtors por columna
if (!exists("default_search_columns")) default_search_columns <- NULL

set.seet(1234)
diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]


ui <- function(request) {fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "diamonds"',
        checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in diamonds to show:",
                           names(diamonds), selected = names(diamonds))
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "mtcars"',
        helpText("Click the column header to sort a column.")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        'input. Dataset === "iris"',
        helpText("Display 5 records by default.")
      ),
      bookmarkButton()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds",
         DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"),
         verbatimTextOutput("filtros")
        ),
        tabPanel("mtcars", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
        tabPanel("iris", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable3"))
      )
    )
  )
)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # choose columns to display

  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE], 
    filter = "top",

    options = list( 
      stateSave = FALSE#,
      #searchCols = default_search_columns,
      #search = list(regex = FALSE, caseInsensitive = FALSE, search = default_search)
    )
  )

  # Creamos un proxy de mytable1
  # Util para modificar un datatable desde el server (se ve mas adelente)
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('mytable1')
  
  #Mostramos la lista de filtros (Al principio solo lo use para poder ver
  #la reactividad de los filtros en la app, pero decido dejarlo ya que
  #esta solucion tiene un pequeño problema que explico al final)
  output$filtros<-renderText({input$mytable1_search_columns})

  observe({
    #Obtenemos los datos del url
    #El valor reactivo en este observe es session$clientData$url_search
    #Solo cambia una vez cuando inicia la session
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    #El sig if asegura que solo se actualicen los filtros si son pasados mediante el url
      if (!is.null(query[['mytable1_search_columns']])) {
        
        ## obtenemos los filtros de columas del url
        default_search_columns <-query$mytable1_search_columns
        #Ya que del url se obtiene un texto en formato json es necesario pasarlo a un objeto r
        #para eso uso fornJSON de jsonlite
        default_search_columns<-fromJSON(default_search_columns,simplifyVector = T)

        #Obtenemos el filtro general
        #Tambien hace falta hacer una tranformacion a objeto r pero es mas senilla pues solo es un character 
        default_search <-eval(parse(text=query$mytable1_search))

        #Actualizamos el DT usando el proxy
        proxy %>% updateSearch(keywords =
          list(global = default_search, columns = c("",default_search_columns)))
        }
  })
  
  # sorted columns are colored now because CSS are attached to them
  output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE))
  })
  
  # customize the length drop-down menu; display 5 rows per page by default
  output$mytable3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 5))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

El problema que mencione en el comentario es que no se muestra el icono para cancelar los filtros en la nueva sesión. Por lo que deje el `output$filtros` así el usuario tiene un vistazo de donde están los filtros.

Comment: Eres un genio! Muchísimas gracias!